# c# combobox drop down click deletes everything in textbox

Tags: c#, autocomplete, combobox, click

I have a windows program (.NET 4.5) that has a combobox with custom dropdown data. My autocomplete type is set to AppendSuggest, so that the customer can easily type in a name, press tab or enter, and then move on to the next box to fill in.

When the combobox loses focus (goes to another control), the program will parse the text in the textbox. If the name exists in the database, it will attach that person to this instance, otherwise it will create a new person with the name (properly cased) in the database.

Pressing tab allows the autocomplete box to fill in the remaining text and it successfully attaches it to the database. However, if the enter button is pressed or, more importantly, the customer tries to click on a user from the autocomplete drop down list, the textbox simply deletes all text in it and moves on to the next box with nothing in it.

I can't find out how to intercept the data that the user clicks. Ideally, I just want the user to click an item from the dropdown list and have it fill the text in, then parse that text and move on.

I have also checked my code and there is no where in the code that deletes the text from this combobox. It seems to be happening by itself behind the scenes.

Also, I am a somewhat advanced programmer in C#, and although I really haven't worked with autocomplete, I am baffled that I am stumped on something as simple as this.